# the date of birth on my edit of a client is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date

Hi im using ruby on rails, when i enter the date of birth on the years is just giving me from 2007 to 2012, 
i have this command on my _form,html.erb (this is on the views), When im editing a client is when i want to ge the day of birth is just giving me 2007 to 2012.

```
   <div class="field">
     <%= f.label "Fecha de nacimiento:" %>
     <%= f.date_select :fecha_nacimiento %>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use params to specify `start_year` and `end_year` of your select. Example:

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label "Fecha de nacimiento:" %>
  <%= f.date_select :fecha_nacimiento, :start_year => 1950, :end_year => (Time.now.year - 10) %>
</div>
```

Look at `:end_year`, I used `Time.now.year - 10` because I assumed that the minimum age to register is 10 years old.

Boa sorte =]

Reference: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-date_select

Comment: Nice =). And don't forget to [mark this answer as the accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)